# Calculate frame PTS according to elapsed time when encoding with libav

Tags: c, encoding, libav, libavcodec, multimedia

I'm building a library to record X11 windows. In order to keep a steady frame rate, I measure the elapsed time between frames and wait as needed. It works well when the encoding procedure goes faster than the expected framerate, but if the encoding is slower and it cannot keep up with the frame rate, something curious happens: the recorded video looks "sped up".

That's because, for a time span of 10 seconds and a frame rate of 60fps, there should be 600 frames, but the computer is too slow and is only capable of recording 300 frames, so the frame that should appear on `t = x` ends up appearing at `t = x/2`, because I'm calculating the PTS according to the number of frames, not the time elapsed from start.

I initially calculate the time base using:

```
    int outputFrameRate = 60;
    double outputFramePeriod = 1.0 / outputFrameRate * 1000;
    AVRational timeBase = { 1, outputFrameRate };
```

I then use it in the `AVCodecContext` instance:

```
    pCodecCtx->time_base = timeBase;
```

And then, I have an increasing `framecnt` counter that is used to calculate the pts of each output frame like so:

```
    pOutputFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(framecnt, pCodecCtx->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);
```

I now have an `elapsedTime` variable with the time elapsed from the beginning in milliseconds. How would I go about calculating the `pts` using that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the timebase to `{1, 1000}` and pass the `elapsedTime` to the rescale function.

Frequency: 1/60 => number of frame (duration of one frame is 1/60 seconds; framerate: 60)
Frequency: 1/1000 => number of milliseconds (duration of one frame is 1/1000 seconds or one ms; framerate: 1000)

From ffmpeg doc:

> rescale_q is mathematically equivalent to a * bq / cq.

Frame number to milliseconds:

```
framecnt: 3 (frames)
bq: 1/60
cq: 1/1000
3 * (1/60) / (1/1000) = 50 (ms)
```

Milliseconds to frame number:

```
framecnt: 50 (ms)
bq: 1/1000
cq: 1/60
50 * (1/1000) / (1/60) = 3 (frames)
```